# Can I handle any exception in step-function state where it invokes a lambda and waiting for task token?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have a step-function definition where a state is invoking a lambda and waiting for a task token. I have added a catch to handle any exception. The state definition-

```
"Invok Handler Lambda": {
        "Type": "Task",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken",
        "Parameters": {
            "FunctionName": "${my_lambda}",
            "Payload": {
                "TaskToken.$": "$$.Task.Token",
                "Input.$": "$"
            }
        },
        "ResultPath": null,
        "Next": "Invoke Completer Lambda",
        "TimeoutSeconds": 600,
        "Retry": [
            {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                    "ErrorA",
                    "ErrorB"
                ],
                "IntervalSeconds": 1,
                "BackoffRate": 2,
                "MaxAttempts": 2
            },
            {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                    "ErrorC"
                ],
                "IntervalSeconds": 5
            }
        ],
        "Catch": [
            {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                    "States.ALL"
                ],
                "Next": "Handle Error"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Step function is working fine. But it doesn't proceed to `Handle Error` state if the lambda `my_lambda` itself failed for some reason.

Is there any way to tell step-function to proceed to the next state in this situation?

Comment: I was exploring with same kind of problem and wrote an article, see if it can help you.
https://medium.com/@alihasanibd?source=rss-8971ceb8f040------2

Answer (score 1):

When you use .waitForTaskToken, that is expected. You are telling Step Functions to invoke a function and asynchronously and then wait to be called back. In that case, you need to implement a mechanism to close the loop and call back to Step Functions with the [SendTaskFailure API Action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_SendTaskFailure.html).

I'm not sure what is driving your need to use callback here, but I'm assuming your function does something like store a record in a database, run some other business logic, then pass the TaskToken to something downstream which is eventually responsible for returning a response. If not, then you probably should just use Request Response. If so, then it's generally a best practice to set `HeartbeatSeconds` and to have your Function or the other downstream responsible component make [SendTaskHearbeat](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_SendTaskHeartbeat.html) calls so you can detect when something dies unexpectedly.

Comment: So, when I call `SendTaskFailure` API with the token then the step-function will proceed and the exception passed in that API call will be caught in `Catch` block? And it is mandatory I handle the exception in my lambda also?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I did a mistake in the step definition. In `Handle Error` state I was looking for some input supposed to come form the upper states. But as you can see, in catch block I haven't passed that explicitly. That's why in `Handle Error` state I was only getting `Error` and `Cause`. So, to fix it I had to re-define the state like -

```
"Invok Handler Lambda": {
    "Type": "Task",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken",
    "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "${my_lambda}",
        "Payload": {
            "TaskToken.$": "$$.Task.Token",
            "Input.$": "$"
        }
    },
    "ResultPath": null,
    "Next": "Invoke Completer Lambda",
    "TimeoutSeconds": 600,
    "Retry": [
        {
            "ErrorEquals": [
                "ErrorA",
                "ErrorB"
            ],
            "IntervalSeconds": 1,
            "BackoffRate": 2,
            "MaxAttempts": 2
        },
        {
            "ErrorEquals": [
                "ErrorC"
            ],
            "IntervalSeconds": 5
        }
    ],
    "Catch": [
        {
            "ErrorEquals": [
                "States.ALL"
            ],
            "ResultPath": "$.error_info",
            "Next": "Handle Error"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, the `"ResultPath": "$.error_info",` in catch block fixed the issue